# Matching a substring from a substring list in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, substring

I have a list of substrings which has about 10000 entries -

```
substr_ls = ['N_COULT16_1 1', 'S_COULT2', 'XBG_F 1', 'FAIRWY_3', .....]
```

I have a list of strings which has about 100 entries -

```
main_str_ls = ['N_COULT16_1 1XF', 'S_COULT2_RT', 'XBG_F TX300 1', 'FAIRWY_34_AG', ....]
```

As you see, the substrings are not perfect substrings of strings from `main_str_ls`. The sequence of alphabets, numbers, etc from substring will have to match the sequence from string for it to be a match. For example - `'XBG_F 1'` is a match with `'XBG_F TX300 1'` because the sequence is a match even though there is a `'TX300'` in the middle of `'XBG_F'` and `'1'`  What I'm currently doing is using this function -

```
def is_subsequence(pattern, items_to_use):
    items_to_use = (x for x in items_to_use)
    return all(any(x == y for y in items_to_use) for x, _ in itertools.groupby(pattern))
```

from [Finding a substring in a jumbled string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60723128/finding-a-substring-in-a-jumbled-string) by iterating over `main_str_ls` (contents of `main_str_ls` used as `items_to_use`) and `substr_ls` (contents of `substr_ls` used as `pattern`) and when I find a match, it breaks the loop and does some stuff. Something like this -

```
for main_str in main_str_ls:
    main_str = main_str.strip()
    for substr in substr_ls:
        substr = substr.strip() 
        if is_subsequence(substr, main_str):
            **do stuff**
```

Is there a better way or a pythonic approach for doing this?

Comment: I would change the `substr_ls` list into a list of regex's `re_str_ls`. `"XBG_F 1"` could become `r"XBG_F.*1"`, then use `if re.match(re_str, test_str): ...`

Answer (score 1):

One of the diffence between what you need vs the jumbled string question is they are concerned about allowing repeats. I don't think you can use that design directly.
Instead, try this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-two-strings-find-first-string-subsequence-second/

Comment: the best way to go about will still be to iterate over both the lists, right?

Comment: Yes the complexity is O(MN(L1+L2)). Given your problem size I think it is workable